# Lightswitch readonly label different text for label and value

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a details screen in Lightswitch that displays a couple of readonly fields (using the label control).  The way it renders these is that the label "header" (displaying the field name) is the same font and weight as the label value. It does not seem that this can be changed in a custom Theme Extension.  I would have expected the label value to use a different text/brush setting to that of the label header. What I would like to achieve is for the label field headers to use a bold font and the label field values to use a non-bold font.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

LightSwitch only uses *bold* for the labels of *required* properties. What you want is "doable", but you have to get your hands a bit dirty, by creating a class that implements *IThemeExtension*.

If you're up for some coding, this blog post describes a way of doing it (either with or without the *Extensions Made Easy* extension). Though it actually does the *opposite* of what you want (turns bold *off*), you can modify the technique to give you what you want (turn bold *on*).

[How to make your required fields NOT have a bold label using Extensions Made Easy… (By Kirk Brownfield)](http://janvanderhaegen.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/how-to-make-your-required-fields-not-have-a-bold-label-using-extensions-made-easy-by-kirk-brownfield)

Answer (score 0):

[Jewel Lambert](http://dotnetlore.com/using-visualtreehelper-to-perform-lightswitch-wizardry/) has written a helper class that will allow you to change the various style elements of your controls.

She's doing the same thing that Kirk Brownfield is doing in Yann's answer, messing with the Silverlight XAML. I just found her method a little easier to follow.